# Laravel 4, passing calculations from a table to a view

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, view

I have a table with lots of numerical data.  I have a view called stats.blade.php where I want to use the data from the table "as is"

Here is the route.php

```
Route::get('stats', 'StatController@stats');
```

Here is the controller:

```
public function stats()
{
    $title = "Stats";
    $stats = DB::table('stat_data')->get();
    return View::make('stats')->with('stats', $stats)->with('title',$title);
}
```

I understand this simple process and I am able to use the data from the table in the stats view.  However I also want to manipulate the data in the table to create new php variables to use in the stats view.  I created a directory in app called calculations and there are several files in there that do a number of calculations from this "stat_data" table.  I am redesigning this site using laravel4, so before I just called require_once"path_to_file" on the page I want to use the new calculated variables.

My questions is what is the best way to pass those calculated variables done in app/calculations/files.php from the stats_table into the stats view?

Answer (score 1):

Accordig to the MVC pattern, your views should not do too much, calculations is one of those things they should not do, because, if you ever need to use those calculations in any other place you'll have to copy them and then you'll have duplicate code that might be different.

What you should do is to create a class to process your calculations and generate an array to be used in your views:

```
public function stats()
{
    $title = "Stats";

    $stats = DB::table('stat_data')->get();

    $stats = new \Calculations\CalculateData($stats);

    return View::make('stats')->with('stats', $stats)->with('title',$title);
}
```

The best way to use PSR-4 and a namespace, for instance: `Calculations`:

Add the namespace to your composer.json pointing to the folder where your namespaced classes are:

```
"psr-4": {
    "Calculations\\": "app/calculations"
},
```

Create the class class 'CalculateData' in

```
app/calculations/CalculateData.php
```

Having this as base code:

```
<?php namespace Calculations;

class CalculateData() {

}
```

Execute

```
composer dump-autoload
```

Once so composer build your autoload psr4 namespaces and you're good to go. If you create new classes inside the same namespace, you don't have to run it again.

Comment: I have now been able to execute the above code.  However I am having trouble passing $stats (aka table('stat_data') ) to the calculation file so I can loop through the table and preform the calculations.    I tried to pass the table into a function in the calculation file but with no luck.

Comment: If you don't show us your full code, or at least a good part of it, it's hard to help, it's a guessing game...

Comment: This answer got me started in a better direction.  I have rephrased this question into what I think is a clearer post with better code [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22288108/passing-hundreds-of-variables-from-controller-to-view-in-laravel)